# 2.7 How to make an anime looking object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

I'm wondering how I would make an object have lines on some edges when rendered, like it was
drawn. I believe the feature is called freestyle, and I activate it in the render options, but my test cube doesn't render with the lined edges. What I'm asking, to be clear, is how to make an object that renders with hard lines on edges to give the appearance of being drawn in blender 2.7 cycles render. The blender wiki has outdated info about this.

Comment: Note that it takes a lot more than edge lining to make something look anime or drawn. You will also need to use toon shaders in your materials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable freestyle in the properties->Render window:
You can control the line thickness there.

[image]

The controls for the shading are in properties->scene->line_style->**Freestyle Line set** and **Line style**.

[image]

Comment: The line thickness control in the Render window is Global line thickness. However, you almost never want to actually change it there. Use thickness control of individual linesets within the render layer options.